# "Not a managed type..." Error while starting spring boot application. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-management

I'm working on a complex project and I've decided to separate it in several small projects.

There are 2 small projects that all projects are using:

1. Utils: A project with common functions and HTTP calls;
2. Models: A project with all my entity objects.

So, **utils** project is made of @Service and **models** project is made of @Entity, just to give a quick explanation.

When I have all projects downloaded and working on my local computer when I start an application that uses models and utils projects it works perfectly fine.
When I delete models and utils from my local computer and start using it from my maven repository, the "not a managed type" error happens and I can't start my application. The same happens on a server.

On my spring boot project main class, I've tried several things, like:

- @EntityScan( basePackages - ... specified all packages.
- @ComponentScan(basePackages = ... specified all packages.

But nothing seems to work. I ran out of options and I'm wondering if my project is fundamentally wrong and I should rebuild my project structure into something different.

Basically:

- I have 3 projects, A, B, and C;
- C project has a dependency on project A and B. B project has a dependency on project A.
- When I start project C, it does not load projects A and B into context and fails to start the application, trowing the "not a managed type: com.company.project-b.Class" error.

Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean 'delete from my local computer'? You need them on your local computer. Maven usually downloads them to ~/.m2/repository. Are the libraries there? And are they the correct ones, i.e. with the @Service annotations?

Comment: Oh right. I'm using eclipse IDE, I just deleted the projects from my workspace. The downloaded maven jars are still there.
Yes, they are the correct ones, I just exported them after I ran the application (with all projects on my workspace) successfully.

Comment: To eliminate possible problems with your IDE, can you try running 'mvn spring-boot:run' on a command line? If that fails, too, can you show us the pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I spent so much time trying to discover the real problem and it was very simple. I had imported only the mandatory libs to compile my entity project, but I also needed to import some spring boot dependencies in order to make it work.

Basically, I just copied the pom.xml from my application project to the entity project and it worked.